Togglz supports Java 21 and Spring 3.4?
I'm getting this error after upgrade my app to Java 21 and Spring 3.4:
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: 
Error creating bean with name 'togglz-org.togglz.spring.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.TogglzProperties': 
Could not bind properties to 'TogglzProperties'

My application.yaml has the togglz prefix, and it worked at java 17 and Spring 2.7.5
Any one getting this error too?
I tried to look for breaking changes into release logs from https://github.com/togglz/togglz/releases
but found nothing.

Just added the spring validation  dependency:

implementation
'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'

It's worked again.
